# AWS- subdomain doesn't support HSTS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, .htaccess

I am using Semrush and I have this one notice that is really bothering me and want to get rid of. 1 subdomain doesn't support HSTS for the subdomain: [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)    , here is my .htdocs file:

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^example\.com$
    RewriteRule .* https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <If "%{REQUEST_SCHEME} == 'https' || %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} == 'https'">
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"
    </If>
</IfModule>
```

I add this part at the end:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <If "%{REQUEST_SCHEME} == 'https' || %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} == 'https'">
            Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"
        </If>
    </IfModule>
```

But still nothing, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1 subdomain doesn't support HSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66901487/1-subdomain-doesnt-support-hsts)

Comment: I did see that and no, it did not solve my issue

Comment: Try removing this `Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"` from Rewrite rules and check

Comment: @Haridarshan I tried that and it did not work

Comment: Please, consider carefully read [this wonderful article](https://www.danielmorell.com/blog/how-to-configure-hsts-on-www-and-other-subdomains) from Daniel Morell, it provides different options and advice about how to deal with and correctly configure HSTS. In addition, also mentioned in the article, try using `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` to query and manage your domain in the Known HSTS Host list. I hope it helps.

Comment: "here is my .htdocs file" - Do you mean `.htaccess`? Do you have access to the server config? Do you have other subdomains that do support HSTS? Is the subdomain in question the `www` subdomain or something else?

Comment: yes .htaccess I mean

Comment: the subdomain in question is www

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Options -Indexes
>
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>     Options +FollowSymLinks
>     RewriteEngine On
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
>     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
>     RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
>     RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^example\.com$
>     RewriteRule .* https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
>     Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
> </IfModule>
> <IfModule mod_headers.c>
>     <If "%{REQUEST_SCHEME} == 'https' || %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} == 'https'">
>         Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"
>     </If>
> </IfModule>
> ```

There are a number of issues here that will prevent HSTS from working properly and some additional optimisations that should be made.

1. You are not redirecting `http://www.example.com` (ie. the www subdomain) to HTTPS. You need to redirect HTTP+WWW to HTTPS+WWW in order to be HSTS compliant.
2. You are redirecting `http://example.com/` (ie. HTTP + non-www) to HTTPS + WWW. In order to be HSTS compliant, you need to redirect to HTTPS on the *same host* first. ie. `http://example.com/` to `https://example.com/` to `https://www.example.com` (yes, that's two redirects, but it's also rare and will only occur at most once per user-agent, because of the STS header that is returned).
3. Your directives are in the wrong order. Your canonical redirects (ie. HTTP to HTTPS and non-www to www) need to be *before* your front-controller rewrite (the first rule). By placing them after the front-controller they are never going to be processed for anything other than the homepage, directories and static resources. eg. `http://example.com/<some-url>` will never be redirected by the rules as written. Not sure how you are testing HSTS compliance with SEMrush, but with the directives as written then `http://example.com/<some-url>` would fail, since it's not redirected.
4. You should remove the first `Header` directive - this is in direct conflict with the 2nd (correct) `Header` directive. The `always` condition (as used in the second instance) is required in order to set the header on
   the HTTPS 301 redirect (ie. non-2xx response) from non-www to www.
5. You should include the `includeSubDomains` directive on the `Strict-Transport-Security` header in order to cover the www subdomain when the domain apex is requested. Although, *all* subdomains will now be implicitly included. Without this, the www subdomain will need to be explicitly requested. (Ok, you are redirecting to www anyway in the next request.)
6. You should remove the `<IfModule>` wrappers; they are not required. These directives are mandatory, they are not *optional* (which is implied by the presence of these wrappers). Your site will presumably fail if mod_rewrite is not available and you will not be HSTS compliant.

   See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/112602/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters stack for more info on this:
   [Is Checking for mod_rewrite Really Necessary?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/112600/is-checking-for-mod-write-really-necessary)
7. I assume from the earlier HTTP + non-www redirect that you are not behind a front-end proxy (or load balancer) that manages your SSL, in which case the check for `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}` in the later `<If>` expression should be removed. If you are not behind a "proxy" then it would be possible to fake a request to prevent the `STS` header being sent back (a user should not be able to do this).

   Conversely, if you are behind a "proxy" then the check for  `%{REQUEST_SCHEME} == 'https'` is redundant - but causes no harm. Incidentally, the use of `REQUEST_SCHEME` assumes you are on Apache 2.4+ (which I expect you are), however, if you are still on Apache 2.2 then this check will fail and the STS header will not be set.

So, taking the above points into consideration, your `.htaccess` file should be written like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS on the same host (requirement of HSTS)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect non-www to www (HTTPS only)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Front-controller
RewriteRule ^index\.php/ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]

<If "%{REQUEST_SCHEME} == 'https'>
    # The "always" condition is required to set the header on the HTTPS redirect
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
</If>
```

Additional notes:

- I've used `HTTP_HOST` instead of `SERVER_NAME` since you *need* the hostname present on the request. By default `SERVER_NAME` is the same as `HTTP_HOST`, but this can vary based on the server config.
- There is no reason to only apply the canonical redirect when a non-empty User-Agent string is present on the request (a malicious request could suppress the User-Agent string) as you had originally, so I've removed this condition. If anything, you would block such requests.
- The regex `^` in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is more optimal than `.*` since it only needs to be successful - it doesn't need to actually *match* anything since it is not being used later.
- The additional `RewriteRule ^index\.php/ - [L]` directive before the "front-controller" is simply an optimisation to prevent rewritten URLs from being unnecessarily passed through the filesystem checks that follow.

#### Reference / See also:

- See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/131970/1243) to a related question on the Webmasters stack:
  [HSTS implementation in .htaccess when using www subdomain](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/115125/hsts-implementation-when-using-www-tld)
- See [my answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251218/6744) to a related question on Code Review:
  [HSTS Recommendations in `.htaccess`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250805/hsts-recommendations-in-htaccess)
- HSTS Preload List Submission (the basic requirements are the same) https://hstspreload.org/
- RFC6797 - HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS): https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6797

---

**UPDATE:** Try the following instead. Since you are on AWS, you'll probably need to check the `X-Forwarded-Proto` HTTP request header instead of the `HTTPS` Apache server variable in order to determine whether the request to the client is secure or not.

The changes required are to the HTTP to HTTPS redirect (first rule) and the `<If>` expression at the end.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS on the same host (requirement of HSTS)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect non-www to www (HTTPS only)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Front-controller
RewriteRule ^index\.php/ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]

<If "%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} == 'https'>
    # The "always" condition is required to set the header on the HTTPS redirect
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
</If>
```

Comment: This did not work, it just kept redirecting and completely broke my site

Comment: @user979331 Ah OK, you may be using AWS "load balancer" (or related) services? In which case you'll probably need to check the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header instead of the `HTTPS` server variable in order to determine whether the client request is secure or not. I've updated my answer with a revised code sample at the end. (However, this would mean that the code you had initially that checked `%{HTTPS} !=on` was wrong - although the redirect loop would have been avoided in that case because you were redirecting non-www to www in the same rule.)

Comment: I'll check it out shortly

Comment: I tried your new code, same result, keeps redirecting too many times

Comment: @user979331 Make sure you've cleared your browser cache and any intermediary caches. 301 (permanent) redirects are cached persistently, including any erroneous redirects. (Test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.) What is it redirecting from/to (and the status codes you are seeing)? (Check the network traffic in the browser to determine this.)

Comment: @user979331 BTW, you should remove the `Header` directive and clear the STS status in the browser until you get this redirect loop resolved.

Comment: I am getting 301 Moved Permanently, its going from the non www site to the www site then back to non www, then back to www, and so on

Comment: @user979331 And HTTPS in all cases? Or is that also flipping from HTTP to HTTPS to HTTP etc? The directives above will _only_ redirect to www, they don't redirect back to non-www. So if you are seeing a redirect back to non-www then "something else" would seem to be doing that. Do you have any other `.htaccess` files? Any directives in the server config? Any redirects in the application itself?

Comment: @user979331 Change the above redirects to `R=302` and clear your browser cache. Check the network traffic again in the browser... do all the status codes change to 302? NB: There is a "disable cache" checkbox in the network tab in Chrome - this should be checked whilst testing (with the dev tools open).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to fix this via DNS record and .vconfig file? For my websites, I have:

1. DNS A records for main domain (`A domain.com 123.123.123.123`)
2. Second DNS A record for www (`A www 123.123.123.123`)

and then in domain.com.vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/path_to_root

    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

</VirtualHost>
```

The rewrite rule forces HTTPS.

If you want to force HTTPS for specific domain, both in .vhost or .htaccess you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain1.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

and for specific folder:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(folder1|folder2|folder3) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to change the folder references to the actual directory names.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what I am suppose to do here, I have a .conf file, is there away I can share this with you?

Comment: @user979331 can you post it here? You can remove dir paths to preserve your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to route your DNS via Cloudflare (even on their free plans), you'll be able to enable HSTS at the click of a button (including for subdomains). Loads of other benefits for speed and security too which might also help with your SEMRush report